# PHP and Ajax updating values

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to dynamically update text on a PHP page via AJAX. But, instead of the text coming through at different intervals, it all comes at once. Maybe this is the wrong approach.

index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Please Update!</title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function(){
       $.post("hello.php", function(data){
           var success = $("#update");
           success.css("color", "green");
           success.html("> \r " + data + ".");
       });
    });
</script>
      
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="update"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

hello.php

```
<?php
    echo "Hello World\n";
    sleep(1);
    echo "\rFoobar\n";
    sleep(1);
    echo "\rBazboo\n";
?>
```

I'd like the text to overwrite itself after one second but it comes barreling down the pipe all at once. ;_;

Comment: It doesn't work that way, echo outputs statements , your sleep code just pauses the execution of the script. You might want a variable and then echo that variable

Comment: you have to do anyone of the follwing...
1) call ajax again and again with parameter... put if statement in hello.php...
2) make array in hello.php... then loop output data with timeout...

Comment: @Ainz-sama - Ah, I had a feeling this wasn't going to be so simple, thank you.

Comment: @AntonyJack: Yikes, that's painful just to read. Is there any other approach which would work better for text coming in at different intervals? And thank you.

Comment: whats ur intention... output get by waiting 1 second or output display by 1 second interval...   which means php side or js side...

Comment: @AntonyJack, Basically I'm downloading a file in the background and the text from the PHP page is intended to give updates on the the status in different values like speed, amount downloaded, etc.

Comment: if youre intention is to show a download progress then you can use the xhr parameter in ajax

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this, but it might help you to do...

in **PHP**

```
<?php
        $result[] = "Hello World\n";
        $result[] = "\rFoobar\n";
        $result[] = "\rBazboo\n";
        print_r($result);
 ?>
```

in **Ajax result**

```
$.post("hello.php", function(data){
   for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      setTimeout(() => {
           // your stuff to do is here by 1 second interval...
           var success = $("#update");
           success.css("color", "green");
           success.html("> \r " + data[i] + ".");
      }, 1000*i);
   }
});
```

**Simple Representation**

```js
var data = ["Hello World\n","\rFoobar\n","\rBazboo\n"];
 for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
         console.log(data[i]);
    }, 1000*i);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, on both your answer and the other when I try it the behavior is somewhat what I'm looking for, but it only outputs one character at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Like Antony suggested. You could create an array in php and encode it as Json
and then create a settimeout().

php

```
$data = array("Hello World","Foobar","BazBoo");
echo json_encode($data);
```

jQuery ~ JavaScript

```
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "hello.php",
    success: (res) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            setTimeout(() => {
               // or use .html(res[i])
                $("#update").text(res[i] + "<br>");
            }, 1000 * i);

        }


    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, on both your answer and the other when I try it the behavior is somewhat what I'm looking for, but it only outputs one character at a time.